# How to get server.Mappath in console application c#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, console-application

How to use server.MapPath in the console application using c#. I tried the below code but I am not  getting my pdf file. Kindly suggest in this.

```
 string[] pdf_file = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Folder\" + fileName);
```

Comment: `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory`

Comment: "I am not getting my pdf file" ..... little vague don't you think?  How are we supposed to know what is happening here?

Comment: What do you want to get? A pdf file as stream? `Directory.GetFiles` returns file paths for the pattern you pass as a parameter.

Comment: `GetFiles()` doesn't take a filename as parameter, you have to supply a path, so for example `var pdfFiles = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Folder");`
If you want pdf files only then use `var pdfFiles = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Folder", "*.pdf");`
If you want a specific file then use `var pdfFiles = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Folder", filename);`. But I don't see the point of that last one, if you know the filename why are you calling `Directory.GetFiles()`?

Comment: faceing an error:An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Comment: Environment.CurrentDirectory

Comment: i m generating the crystal report and converted into pdf and saved into the appliacation folder and i need to get the same converted pdf file and attach to the mail.so that i am using Directory.GetFiles(). @Neil Humby

Comment: @harathiviru look at my example code, you are not passing the correct strings into `Directory.GetFiles()`. The first parameter is the folder name, in your case "C:\Folder". The second parameter is the search pattern, for example "*.pdf" will return all pdf files. So, `Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Folder", "*.pdf");` will return all files in C:\Folder\ that are .pdf files.

Answer (score 8):

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
string path = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "//XMLFile1.xml";
xmlDoc.Load(path);
XmlReader xmlReader = new XmlNodeReader(xmlDoc);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.ReadXml(xmlReader);
```

Answer (score 3):

Actually we need to locate application directory which contain folder along with bin folder, and our executable file is present in bin/debug. So we can get the executable file path using `Environment.CurrentDirectory` and from that we can extract our path as below,

```
string filepath = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
Console.WriteLine(filepath.Split(new String[] {"bin"}, StringSplitOptions.None)[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the Security access details of "C:\Folder\". You should grant read rights to user group **IIS_IUSRS**. If you want to allow IIS to be able to save files to this folder then grant Write access too.